# Property 'wakeLock' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: angular, typescript, navigator

I need to use the Screen Wake Lock API in my angular app
here is my code

```
if ('wakeLock' in navigator) {
         await navigator.wakeLock.request();
        
}
```

However, Angular compilation fails with the following error:

```
Error: src/app/feature/test/test/test.component.ts:20:42 - error TS2339: Property 'wakeLock' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

Angular version and information

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 13.0.3
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1300.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.0.3
@angular-devkit/core            13.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.0.3
@angular/cdk                    13.0.3
@angular/cli                    13.0.3
@angular/flex-layout            13.0.0-beta.36
@angular/material               13.0.3
@schematics/angular             13.0.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.4.4
```

How can fix typescript to contain Screen Wake Lock API and can compile codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, after two weeks I found a way that supports this by adding the DefinitelyTyped. Two-step can fix this.

1. Install the `@types/dom-screen-wake-lock` package

```
npm i @types/dom-screen-wake-lock -D
```

2. After installing the package you must add types to `tsconfig.json` like this

```
{
...
   "compilerOptions":{
...
         "types":[
...
              "dom-screen-wake-lock"
...
            ]
...
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did to make it work:

```
const anyNav: any = navigator
if ('wakeLock' in navigator) {
  anyNav["wakeLock"].request("screen")
}
```

I first tried adding the DefinitelyTyped definition which fixed the editor throwing errors, but it was still causing compilation to fail. This did the trick, basically we are saving the navigator to an any type variable which allows us to call any properties or methods without type checking.

The if statement allows for checking that wakelock is supported by the browser before trying to call it.

Answer (score -1):

Check your security context because Wakelock works only with https enabled: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WakeLock

Comment: The issue is not that it doesn't work, it's that TypeScript gives an error on compilation

Comment: I had exactly the same error and the problem was https. Maby this comment could help people like me finding out this post