# How to keep the screen on indefinitely on a web page on Android with Angular?

Tags: android, angular, mobile, service-worker

I need to implement a functionality to keep the screens of tablets and smartphones on while they are in one of the modules of my application.

I tried using [**Screen Wake Lock API**](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/wake-lock/) but there seems to be some incompatibility with Angular on Android. It works on Windows with or without Angular; works on android without Angular like in this [demo](https://wake-lock-demo.glitch.me/); but it doesn't work on Android with Angular, even though I used exactly the same code from the [demo](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/wake-lock-demo?path=index.html%3A1%3A0).

I had the same problem presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71538643/property-wakelock-does-not-exist-on-type-navigator), but I used the proposed solutions and managed to get around the typo. However, the new issue is while running on Android browsers only, unless there is no `WakeLock` on `window` or `navigator`.

I ran the following tests on Android with Angular, and they all returned `false`, but returned `true` in the Windows browser:

```ts
'wakeLock' in navigator && 'request' in (navigator as any).wakeLock
'WakeLock' in window && 'request' in ((window as any).WakeLock as any)
```

Is there any further configuration required for the Screen Wake Lock API to work on Android with Angular?

Or is there any other way to keep the screen active beyond the time configured on the device, as if it were playing some media?

I'm using:

- Angular 15 with Service Worker;
- Tests in Chrome and Chrome Android 113;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It is necessary to make the application available with **HTTPS**!

As warned in [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WakeLock):

> Secure context: This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

By default HTTPS seems to be required to work, as in the case of the Android browser, but the Windows browser does not require this, for some reason.